# Any possible to have multiple lightning apps on a visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I tried to create multiple Salesforce Lightning applications on a visualforce page. 
The first Salesforce lightning application could be loaded successfully but the second is not.

## Error message.

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: $Lightning.use() already invoked with application: c:SelfRegApp
    at Object.use (lightning.out.delegate.js?v=NnIJH4aLacQ2kst_AkZ-mQ:132)
    at Object.use (lightning.out.js?v=2:59)
    at eval (eval at VFCall.then.e (login.js:85), <anonymous>:1:12)
    at VFCall.then.e (login.js:85)`

## 1st Salesforce lightning app

```
<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:SelfRegApp", function () {
    $Lightning.createComponent("c:SelfRegister",
    {},
    "reg",
    function (cmp) {
    debugger
    });
    });
</script>
```

## 2nd Salesforce lightning app

```
<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:SelfRegApp2", function () {
    $Lightning.createComponent("c:SelfRegister2",
    {},
    "reg",
    function (cmp) {
    debugger
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am sure you cannot, but are you doing this just for test? Because in practical scenarios I wouldn't imagine two "apps" invoked from a vf page.

Comment: Your app is made up of components right? So create a 3rd App and add all the componenets from the 2 mentioned apps and then show it in VF page.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal yes, you got it. if this is the only way then we will try that. The best expectation is to have multiple lightning applications at a a visualforce page

Comment: One use case is to be able to use the standard component <analytics:reportChart> (which uses Lightning Out under the hood apparently) in a VF page along with a custom LWC component... I'm trying to do that now, and this limitation is a blocker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_markup.htm) specifically states that you can only use one app per page:

> You can’t use more than one Lightning dependency app on a page. You can call $Lightning.use() more than once, but you must reference the same dependency app in every call.

However, you can put both components into a single dependency app, and instantiate them independently.

```
$Lightning.use("c:SelfRegDep", function () {
$Lightning.createComponent("c:SelfRegister",
{},
"reg1",
function (cmp) {
debugger
});
});
$Lightning.use("c:SelfRegDep", function () {
$Lightning.createComponent("c:SelfRegister2",
{},
"reg2",
function (cmp) {
debugger
});
});
```

Pleases note that increasing the number of dependencies will also increase the load time, since all dependencies must be preloaded.

Comment: How can I remove the existing Salesforce lightning  application and load another one at the same visualforce page? We'are implementing this feature in a single page application.

Comment: @Dummy you can't, short of refreshing the page entirely, which of course defeats the purpose of a single page application.

Comment: There's no other way to remove the current using Salesforce lightning application and re-init another one on the same visual force page?

Comment: @Dummy There is no documented method for reinitializing Lightning Out in any context.

Comment: Appreciate your answers!!!

Comment: @sfdcfox any thoughts on how to get around the fact that I can't use Lightning Out for my custom LWC alongside the standard VF component <analytics:reportChart> on a single page?  I'm trying to do that now, and this limitation is a big blocker...

Comment: @Bow-chicawow-ers I haven't heard of this limitation. Do you have a reproduceable example? I would be happy to take a look at it for you.

Comment: @sfdcfox very grateful.  I believe this console message says it all: _$Lightning.use() already invoked with application: analytics:reportChartDependencyApp_.  That message will appear after adding a `<analytics:reportChart>` component to a VF page with `$Lightning.use` (Lightning Out) already invoked for a custom LWC.  So it seems to prevent using the [analytics:reportChart](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm?search_text=report) component along with a custom LWC on a VF page, for the reason you detail in your answer here.

Comment: (To expound, the `<analytics:reportChart>` standard VF component utilizes Lightning Out in its implementation, so there's no way to move its report chart contents into a single custom Lightning Out aura app alongside my custom LWC.)

Comment: @Bow-chicawow-ers I figured as such. It's a bummer that's the case. I guess you could iframe two separate pages?