# Lightning record page printable view or PDF

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-web-components, printpdf, printable

I need to create a printable view (or PDF) of a record's Lightning Page (think "tear sheet") that includes a *compact* "details" section, *compact* related list tables, and a custom LWC chart component.  The OOTB solutions don't seem to solve for this well, but I would prefer not to reinvent the wheel and build a printable view from scratch that needs to maintained in parallel with changes to the layout / record page.

### OOTB print options: pros & cons

1. ***Lightning's `Printable View` button***.  **Pros:** (A) prints record details in a compact fashion, (B) easy to maintain.  **Cons:** (A) prints related list records in a very space-inefficient way, (B) prints *just* the details and related lists, and so won't include custom Lightning components that exist on the Lightning record page.
2. ***Browser's native print function***.  **Pros:** (A) prints all items rendered on the Lightning record page (including custom components), (B) easy to maintain.  **Cons:** (A) prints *only* what's *rendered* in the browser, and so won't capture content from hidden tabs, e.g. related lists, (B) is space inefficient and comes with funky style quirks.

### Custom print page: pros & cons

**Pros:** control over getting it to look good (compact and quirk-free)
**Cons:** cost to build & maintain

### Questions

1. Am I missing anything with respect to OOTB print functionality?
2. Is there a relatively low-effort way to "mix & match" the 2 OOTB functionalities ("Printable View" and browser Ctrl+P) to get the compact but comprehensive printable view I'm looking for?  I know in VF there were things like `<apex:page renderAs="pdf">`, `<apex:details>` and `<apex:relatedList>` e.g., that could help toward this end.  Not aware of anything similar in Lightning.

**Update:** I started going down the simple VF page route using the components mentioned above, along with `<analytics:reportChart>`, but unfortunately this analytics VF component uses Lightning Out, and so I [can't use Lightning Out for a 2nd app](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227091/any-possible-to-have-multiple-lightning-apps-on-a-visualforce-page/227095?noredirect=1#comment494238_227095) to host my custom LWC.